# Next/Previous Buttons Show up in Firefox, not Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, zurb-foundation, jekyll

I've got a little div that contains a next/previous button and a Page # out of #. Trouble is, it only shows up in Firefox, not Chrome. It uses Foundation 4's button code and Jekyll's paginator code to create the setup.

You can see it at the bottom right of the page, just above the footer at [tx0rx0.com](http://tx0rx0.com)
Chromium on my laptop shows nothing, but the code is there in the page source viewer. What gives?

Comment: The issue, in my copy of Chrome at least, is that the buttons are hidden behind the footer.  I just changed section#wrap's margin-bottom to -4em and the buttons appeared again.

Comment: If it is through only chrome, you might want to make a script that changes the styles if the user is using chrome.

Comment: Seems kinda inelegant to setup a chrome only script. I wonder why it does that. It's probably related to either how ems are calculated or to my sticky footer solution

Comment: I fixed it by adding a push div, but it seems kinda inelegant to me. If anyone's got a better solution, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .pagination div's container has floated elements but is not cleared.

Since the container is the last element inside #wrap, it is affected by this class which cuts off the floated .pagination :

```
#wrap > *:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 6.25em;
}
```

You can fix this by changing the padding-bottom to margin-bottom, or apply a clear-fix to the div containing the floated .pagination element.

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: I ended up going with your first suggestion. It seems to have solved the problem. If you could explain a little bit more about the floated uncleared elemtents, and what #wrap > *:last child does, that would be great

Comment: #wrap > * :last-child selects only the last element inside the #wrap div, which happens to be the div containing the pagination. (* selects any element)
With floats, a container will not wrap a floated element unless it is also floated or cleared, a weird quirk in CSS. You can read about it here http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Answer (score 1):

You have this going on:

```
#wrap {
  margin: 0 auto -6.25em;
}
```

And the bottom margin of that container is set to -6.25em. You also have this going on:

```
#wrap > *:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 6.25em;
}
```

Which is effectively selecting the last child `div` of `#wrap` to have a `padding-bottom` of 6.25em. The intention here looks to be that those two would cancel each other out; that is not what's happening though, because the styles are applied to different block elements that are in the normal document flow. So your pager is hidden because of a negative margin.

I'm not sure what your intention is here. The simple fix, unless there's some reason this can't be done, is:

```
#wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And wipe out this:

```
#wrap > *:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 6.25em;
}
```

Comment: I was led to believe this is a good method for forcing the footer to always exist at the bottom of the page. I admit to not completely understanding how it does so.